# efficient way to split temporal Numpy vector automatically

Tags: python, numpy

I have a temporal vector as in the following image:
[image]

Numpy vector:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Jac-wNMDxHS3BnUzBoUkdmOGs/view?usp=sharing

I would like to know an efficient way to split the vector in numpy, and extract the 5 chunks of the signals that drop in amplitude significantly.

I could separate them by considering the amplitude 2.302 as the cut off amplitude and separate them by the initial index when the signal drops bellow this value and the final index when the signal goes above this value.

Any efficient way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

So I've programmed the solution in pure python and lists:

```
vec = np.load('vector_numpy.npy')
# plt.plot(vec)
# plt.show()
print vec.shape

temporal_vec = []
flag = 0
flag_start = 0
flag_end = 0

all_vectors = []
all_index = []

count = -1
for element in vec:
    count = count+1
    #print element
    if element < 2.302:
        if flag_start ==0:
            all_index.append(count)
            flag_start=1
        temporal_vec.append(element)
        flag = 1
    if flag == 1:
        if element >= 2.302:
            if flag_start==1:
                all_index.append(count)
                flag_start=0
            all_vectors.append(temporal_vec)
            temporal_vec = []
            flag = 0

print(all_vectors)

for element in all_vectors:
    print(len(element))
    plt.plot(element)
    plt.show()

print(all_index)
```

Any fancier way in Numpy or better/shorter python code?